# Generate Certificate, Python app, OPC-UA Server <> OPC- UA Client

Tags: python, certificate, plc, opc-ua

i've written a small OPC-UA-Client in Python which acts as datalogger for PLC's with integrated OPC-UA Server.

The Connection with no security works fine but i want to secure it with a certificate.

I can import trusted certificates to the server and export the server certificate but how can i generate my own certificate ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use openssl to generate your own self-Signed certificate.
https://www.openssl.org/source/

Be Carefull with the extensions tho sometimes they demand .der .cer or as .pem and you might get an outform .crt.

How to create them:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS8JFY_9.2.0/com.ibm.lmt.doc/Inventory/security/t_ssl_creating_certs.html

https://dzone.com/articles/secure-communication-with-tls-and-the-mosquitto-broker

Types of encryption:

https://blog.storagecraft.com/5-common-encryption-algorithms/

If you show your program maybe I can help you out.